# Computed Property for Google Datastore

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am not sure exactly how achieve this.

I have a model defined as

```
class Post(ndb.Model):
    author_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Author)
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    title = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    topics = ndb.StructuredProperty(Concept, repeated=True)
    concise_topics = ndb.ComputedProperty(get_important_topics())

    @classmethod
    def get_important_topics(cls):
        cls.concise_topics = filter(lambda x: x.occurrence > 2, cls.topics)
        return cls.concise_topics
```

I like to set the value of concise_topics (Which is on the same type as topics) to a subset acheived via get_important_topics method. This should happen the moment the topics property has been set.

How do I define the "concise_topics" property in the Post class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With class method, you don't have access to the instance values. And also you shouldn't **call** the function, only **pass** it to the computed property, and let it call by itself.

```
class Post(ndb.Model):
    author_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Author)
    content = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    title = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
    topics = ndb.StructuredProperty(Concept, repeated=True)

    def get_important_topics(self):
        return filter(lambda x: x.occurrence > 2, self.topics)

    concise_topics = ndb.ComputedProperty(get_important_topics)
```

As far as I remember the computed property is set on each **put** call, so your topics should be already there by that time.

Comment: I do get a new issue now.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39571299/badrequesterror-blob-enity-proto-or-text-property-concise-topics-must-be-in-a